# KeyNotFoundException in dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I'm a bit baffled here. I'm getting this exception which is telling me this key doesn't exist. When I look at all the key/value pairs in the dictionary in the watch window, the key in question IS THERE!!! I don't think I'm going crazy, but I could be. Am I missing something here? Here's the code:

```
public static List<Quote> GetQuoteHistory(int id)
{
    List<Quote> quotes = DataAccess.GetQuoteHistory(id);
    SetAckCodeDescriptions(quotes);
    return quotes;
}

private static void SetAckCodeDescriptions(IEnumerable<Quote> quotes)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> ackData = GetAcknowlegementData();

    foreach (Quote quote in quotes)
    {
        quote.AckCodes = GetAckCodeHtml(quote.AckCodes, ackData);
    }
}

private static string GetAckCodeHtml(string ackCodes, IDictionary<string, string> ackData)
{
    string[] codes = ackCodes.Split(',');

    string html = string.Empty;
    foreach (string code in codes)
    {
        html += string.Format("<div title='#= {0} #'>#= {1} #</div>, ", ackData[code], code);
    }

    return html.TrimEnd(new []{',', ' '}); // remove extra comma and space
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetAcknowlegementData()
{
    List<AckData> list = DataAccess.GetAcknowlegementData();
    return list.ToDictionary(o => o.AcknowledgementCode, o => o.Description);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `GetAcknowlegementData()`?

Comment: Are you sure the value of `code` is what you expect when it's used as an index? Perhaps it contains extraneous characters / whitespace.

Comment: @SteveTownsend Fair enough. I just wondered if I was missing something. :)

Comment: @Dan J - you're probably right, I deleted my comments.  Logic error in the flow somewhere.

Comment: I looked quite carefully at the code (i.e., key). There doesn't appear to be any white space or other extraneous characters.

Comment: Maybe you've already checked, but I have to ask (since I've done it before...)  How about the string case?  I often convert keys to uppercase or lowercase when creating and getting data from a dictionary

Comment: Just test the Dictionary keys with AckData.Keys.Contains() before accessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to iterate over the value/pair in your dictionary. See if you have actually the element (eyes can lie).

```
foreach (var pair in ackData)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

Comment: and check if your entries in codes contain space at the end after split (trim if they do).

Comment: This was it. There was (at least on some) a space preceeding the code. Thanks for the sanity checks.